# How to catch invalid_client in Spring OAuth + Boot

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I can get some events published to the Event Publisher, like successful client authentication and successful/unsuccessful user authentication.
But when the client credentials are wrong, no events is published.

Here are the logs:

`DEBUG::org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter::doFilter::Request is to process authentication
DEBUG::...ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter::unsuccessfulAuthentication::Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
DEBUG::...ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter::unsuccessfulAuthentication::Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
DEBUG::...ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter::unsuccessfulAuthentication::Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter$1@734b2ca6
DEBUG::org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer::writeWithMessageConverters::Written [error="invalid_client", error_description="Bad client credentials"] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@37536106]`

In **2.0.8-RELEASE** of spring-security-oauth2, there doesn't seem to be a way to set a custom failure handler in the ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter (via AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter).

Also, adding interceptors doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Or I'm just doing it all wrong...

Anyone had any luck catching all authentication events with Spring Boot+OAuth2?